# Using anonymous functions with jquery $.when

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I currently have the following (simplified here) code to action two Ajax calls which I need to complete before processing more code using a when (I know this could be chained but the when construct is expandable).

```
function f1(ID) {  
    return $.ajax({
        url: "'/ajax/getF1/')?>" + '/' + ID,
        dataType: "json"       
    });
}

function f2(ID) {  
    return $.ajax({
        url: "'/ajax/getF2/')?>" + '/' + ID,
        dataType: "json"       
    });
}

 $.when(
   f1(ID),
   f2(ID)
 ).done(function(a1,a2) {
   ....do something...
 });
```

This seems inelegant, so my question is how do I turn the two named function f1 and f2 into anonymous functions called inline.  Simply substituting (say) f1 with the contents of the f1 function doesn't work.

It seems to me that this should be simple, but it's eluding me.

Comment: `function(ID) { /* f1 code */ }, function(ID) { /* f2 code */ }`

Comment: What is `?>` doing without a matching `<?php` before it?

Comment: General rule (assuming your function has no side effects and only performs a return): if `f()` returns `A` and you are calling `g(f())` then you can call `g(A)` because `f() === A`. Basically, if you're calling a function that just returns something, you can always put that something in place of the function call after removing the `return` keyword, of course.

Comment: @Barmar: my bad, copied and adjusted the function in from a view in a template where the actual urls are written in by PHP and missed the ending ?>

Answer (score 4):

You pass promises to `$.when()` not functions.  So, what you could do is this:

```
$.when($.ajax(...), $.ajax(...)).then(...)
```

There is no need for an intermediate function.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
$.when(
  $.ajax({
    url: "'/ajax/getF1/')?>" + '/' + ID,
    dataType: "json"       
  }),
  $.ajax({
    url: "'/ajax/getF2/')?>" + '/' + ID,
    dataType: "json"       
  })
).done(function(a1,a2) {
   ....do something...
})
```